# i can't debug on physical device

Tags: flutter

i am trying to debug on a physical device a flutter app. During launch it freezes on:

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

i run the program with

> flutter run -v

, everything works perfectly.

this is my flutter doctor

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm,
> locale it-IT) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
> (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> (Xcode 14.1) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio
> (version 2021.3) [✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1) [✓] Connected device (4
> available) [✓] HTTP Host Availability
>
> • No issues found!

during startup I get a white screen on the physical device, but I don't get errors of any kind.

help please?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that everythin works when you execute flutter run -v?
If not, what output does it produce?

Comment: when i launch an app with flutter run -v it loads perfectly without errors

Comment: Ok, got it. And how do you try to debug the app? Via which command or tool?

Comment: start debug (F5) vsCode

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me  many times,
when that happened I use `flutter clean` and then close and reopen
vs code and most important I delete my old versions of the app this soluation works fine for me and I hope that helps you

Comment: i ran everything but i get stuck on installing apk

Comment: @MaurizioMancini I told you what I know and what worked for me, but I may suggest you could create a new project and move your old lib folder to the new project